# Shortcut key for context-sensitive help in Intellij Idea (coding in Java)

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Isn't there some shortcut that takes you to context specific help?
For example, if I have my cursor on System.out.println, isn't there some shortcut key I press that takes me to the documentation on this particular method or class where the method is declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View documentation ("Quick Documentation" action):
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

View external documentation ("External Documentation" action):
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
For this to work you need to configure your project so that IntelliJ knows where to look for it (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-external-documentation.html)).

Comment: I can accept that as an answer because it does work.  I remember there being one that goes to an internet online help page....

Comment: @SirFartsalot, I included viewing external docs in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer for the Mac users out there try using F1 for Quick Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs

In the **Project Structure** window > **Platform Settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+S) under **SDKs** you can add a documentation url for the specific SDK version: under **Documentation Paths** tab click on the correct + icon (or use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>). In IntelliJ 2019.3 when you want to add the url it gives you by default the correct url so you can just hit Ok:
JDK 1.8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/
JDK 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/
JDK 13: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/

When you return to your source code you can the select a Java keyword and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and your browser will open and jump automatically to the correct docs for the keyword.